# VLookup + Searching for text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Ive looked around this (awesome) site but as Im not 100% what formula (IF, Match etc) I need its getting quite tricky! I have 2 Workbooks of data that I am working with...

The first has the following columns:

- **School Code, School Name, User ID (blank), User Full Name**

The second has:

- **Name, User ID and School Code**

Im trying to find a formula which will search for the **User Full Name** (not exact matches) column + **Code** (exact) columns, in the Sheet2, and if found; return the User ID from that sheet into Sheet1.

It'd be amazing if the formula could return more than one column (say User ID and Code from the Sheet2) for me to be able to check that the Codes match (they are the only column that is exact!) -- but I dont know if this is even possible?!

Any help immensley appreciated! Feel free to spell it out for me too

Comment: what do you mean by not exact match? can you provide few illustrative examples of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a first stab to your issue:

Let say this is `Sheet1`:

[image: Sheet 1 data]

Let say this is `Sheet2`:

[image: Sheet 2 data]

The formula you can use in `Sheet1`, cell `C2` is:

```
=MAX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10*(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$10=A2)*(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10=Sheet1!D2))
```

Please note this is an array formula you have to validate with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of simply press  <kbd>Enter</kbd> (this will make these `{ }` wrap the formula.

Also note that the formula will check if the `User Full Name` is *exactly* the same as `Name` (I can't see any easy way to handle "not exact matches", please elaborate if you really need this feature).